Event reply in Electron
I am trying to send a success reply from main.js to my frontend customer.js. I want to send the message but do not know how to handle it on the front end. In the frontend, I am using jQuery. The code works so no need to change that just want to handle the event.
This is my code in main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");

ipcMain.on("createCustomer", async (event, data) => {
    const { customerData } = data;
    try {
        const insertCustomerQuery = `
          INSERT INTO customers (company_name, address, phone, gstin, pan, cin)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        `;
        await connection.query(insertCustomerQuery, [
            customerData.companyName,
            customerData.address,
            customerData.phone,
            customerData.gstin,
            customerData.pan,
            customerData.cin,
        ]);
        event.reply(true);
        // win.reload();
        console.log("Data inserted successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        event.reply("createcustomerfailed", error);
        console.error("Error inserting data:", error);
    }
});

In frontend, customer.js the code looks like
$("#saveCustomer").click(async () => {
        try {
            const customerData = saveCustomerData();
            await window.electron.send('createCustomer', { customerData });
            console.log(result);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
});

I want to handle the reply here.
for reference this is my preload.js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'electron',
    {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        },
        invoke: async (channel, data) => {
            return await ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data);
        }
    }
);

